# Lectura y escritura de archivos con modo "w+"

Tags: python, archivo

Mi problema es que al abrir un archivo de texto en 'w+' al parecer se borra todo en el momento que se abre y no me lee lo que esta escrito en el archivo:

```
with open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","w+")as ArchivoTexto:                
    Leer=ArchivoTexto.read()
    print(Leer)
```

Pero si hago lo siguiente:

```
with open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","r")as ArchivoTexto:             
    Leer=ArchivoTexto.read()[:len(ArchivoTexto.read())- 1]                  

with open("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","w")as ArchivoTexto:
    ArchivoTexto.write(Leer)
```

si funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El modo `w+` no significa que puedas leer el contenido previo del archivo una vez abierto y que este se trunque en la primera llamada a `write`, este modo **trunca el archivo nada más abrirlo (o lo crea si no existe)** y colocando el cursor al inicio.

La diferencia con el modo `w`, es que **con `w+` podemos leer del archivo después de escribir**, solo tenemos que posicionar el cursor dónde queramos. Antes de escribir algo podemos leer pero estará vacío por el truncado inicial. En cambio, con el modo `w` tendremos siempre un `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable` ante un intento de lectura.

Si quieres leer el archivo y luego borrar su contenido antes de escribir, puedes usar el modo `r+` o `a+` (si quieres que el archivo se cree de no existir) y truncar el archivo tras la lectura:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    contenido = f.read()
    f.truncate(0)
    f.write("Hola")
```

---

Por cierto, al hacer el slicing no hagas:

```
Leer=ArchivoTexto.read()[:len(ArchivoTexto.read())- 1]
```

usa indices negativos en su lugar, es más eficiente (en tu caso lees y cargas en memoria el archivo completeo dos veces) y más simple:

```
Leer = ArchivoTexto.read()[:-1]
```